# Assigning char pointer to array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

```
 void fun(char arr[]){
 cout<<arr;//successfully received and printed

 }

main(){


   char *ptr="hello";
   fun(ptr);

   /*
   char arr2[]=ptr;  throws error....initialiser fails to determine size of arr2
   */

   getch();
   }`
```

Why am I allowed to pass a char pointer and receive it in array,but can not directly assign char pointer to array.As far I know,assignment takes place implicitly when we pass parameters to a function.So why is this difference in behavior?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The declaration

```
void fun(char arr[]){
```

is equivalent to

```
void fun(char *arr){
```

which means that, in this case, no need of size of character array to be passed to the function. Now `arr` points to the same location as of `ptr`. But in case of

```
char arr2[] = ptr;
```

compiler doesn't know about the size of `ptr` as it is a pointer to first character of string literal `hello` and hence the compiler fails out to determine the size for array `arr2` and it throws the error. You must have to specify the size of array.
The size of character array can be omitted only with the initializer like;

```
char arr2[] = "Hello World";
```

In this case compiler determines the size of array `arr2` from the size of string `Hello World`.

Comment: Pardon me if I am wrong,but I think array name is also a char pointer.so it should work fine even if we do it inside main function.

Comment: No. Arrays and pointers are two different things. Array names are not pointer but decays to pointer to its first element in some cases. You can simply understand it by an example that array names can't be a left operand of `=` operator while pointers can.

Comment: Got it.Thanks.what I observed that array name always decays to pointer if it is used as a parameter to recceive data in a function as I can always increment its and array name is non modifiable l value which cant be incremented,so it must be a pointer.correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand the last sentence: *as I can always increment it*. Could you rephrase it again ?

Comment: In the above example arr++ is valid,which wouldnt be possible if  art would be an array as we cant increment array name.so I concluded that arr[] in fun has decayed to char pointer.